# how to print the formatted text in a text area in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, string-formatting

Actually I am doing label printing I want to print the labels on both sides of the Text Area I want serial no 1 and 2 to be adjacent  actually it is given in a while loop`

```
          while(rs.next())
            {   
            y++;           

                if(y%2==0)
                      {
                     jTextArea3.append("\t\t");        
                     jTextArea3.append(rs.getString("Name")+"\t"+y+"\n");
                     jTextArea3.append("\t\t");                              
                     jTextArea3.append(rs.getString("address")+"\n");
                     jTextArea3.append("\t\t");                 
                     jTextArea3.append(rs.getString("phoneno")+"\n");
                     jTextArea3.append("\t\t");                         
                     jTextArea3.append(rs.getString("nno")); 
                     jTextArea3.append("\n");

                     } 
                     else
                     {

                     jTextArea3.append(rs.getString("Name")+"\t"+y+"\n");
                     jTextArea3.append(rs.getString("address")+"\n");
                     jTextArea3.append(rs.getString("phoneno")+"\n");                                                
                     jTextArea3.append(rs.getString("nno"));
                     jTextArea3.append("\n");

                }
```

Comment: Whats your actual and expected output.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/svjP4.png this is the actual output i get i want the serial no 1 and 2 side by side similarly 3 and 4

Comment: Instead of formatting row by row, format two rows at a time.

Comment: how can I do it i dont get it?

Comment: If there is only one row then just print it. Otherwise, take two rows, print names of these two rows side by side, later address side by side, etc. Later take two more rows, repeat it , etc.

Comment: I dont know how to code it

Comment: Don't worry, in this case just turn off your system and do other activities like chatting with others or something :)